# Diameter of Cayley graphs of symmetric groups

Tags: finite-groups, cayley-graphs

Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters. If we consider the Cayley graph $\Gamma(S_n,C)$, where $C=\{(12),(12\cdots n)\}$, is there any formula for calculating the diameter of $\Gamma(S_n,C)$?

In fact, for an example, I need to know the diameter of this Cayley graph for big numbers, e.g. $n=100$ or $n=1000$.

Comment: We can get an upper bound on the number of elements distance $k$ away from a point, which gives us lower bound on the diameter.  Fix a starting point (such at $e$). 
 Every vertex in the graph is of degree $3$, and so there is $1$ vertex distance $0$ away, $3$ distance $1$, and at most $3\cdot 2^{k-1}$ distance $k$ away for $k\geq 1$.  Summing, there are at most $1+3\cdot 2^k$ vertices distance at most $k$ away.  Since there are $n!$ vertices, if $k< \log_2((n!-1)/3)$, then we will not have exhausted all the vertices.  Therefore, this is a lower bound for the diameter.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks so much for your help, Is there any upper bound for this diameter which is tight? Thanks again

Comment: I don't know myself (I've never thought about this before).  But google allowed me to find the following, which says the answer is $O(n^2)$.  https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Tan.pdf

Comment: @Aaron Thanks so much again. I found the upper bound $(n−1).5n$ in the paper, However, I do not know that it is tight or not. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know how tight it is, but from the lower bound and stirlings approximation, we know that the true order is somewhere between $n\log n$ and $n^2$.  This isn't enough to pin things down up to a constant, but it's not too wide a range.

Comment: Thank you very much again